# How to parse HTML using nokogiri if the required content doesn't have a class or id?

Tags: ruby, parsing, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape some content and parse it using Nokogiri! Got struck now since i am trying to get some text content which is not enclosed with in any kind of tags. Just text and some of it in  tags with out any class or id to it.

Can i find content by searching just the content/text starting and ending of it and get all of it in between?

```
<body>
text <br/>
<ul>
<li>some more text </li>
</body>
```

CSS selectors or Xpath, any solution would be great.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, but I have a guess that you are using the term "hook" in a wrong way.

Comment: Hey, Sorry! I just removed the hook part! Please look at the above html example above, i want the text part of the above html which is not enclosed either in div or any kind of tag. How to find and read that kind of content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require "nokogiri"

Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<_).css("body").children.first.text
<body>
text <br/>
<ul>
<li>some more text </li>
</body>
_
# => "\ntext "


Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<_).css("body").children.first.text.strip
<body>
text <br/>
<ul>
<li>some more text </li>
</body>
_
# => "text"
```